# JQuery single element validation not respecting rules

Tags: jquery, element, validation

I cannot crack this one - I have a simple form with a textbox and button (not submit). I want users to enter an email address and when they press button, it will be added to a list of addresses displayed on a page. I only need to validate user entry to see if it is valid email address.

HTML:

```
<form id="inviteFriendsForm"> 
    Email address: <input type="text" id="cemail" name="someEmail" value="" /> 
    <input type="button" id="addEmail" value="Add email" />  
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#addEmail").click(function() {
    var isValid = $("#inviteFriendsForm").validate({
       rules: { cemail: { required: true, email: true } }
    } ).element("#cemail");

    if(isValid) {
        alert($("#cemail").val());
    }
    else {
        alert('Wrong email');
    }
});
```

The problem I have is that `isValid` variable is always true. Please note that alerts are there not because I would use it to indicate error to the user, code wise I just need to know whether I should continue processing user input or not.

Just for a record, I'm using jQuery Validation Plugin 1.8.0

Thanks a lot,

Antonin

Answer (score 0):

1. Make the button a submit button.
2. Use validate's submitHandler property to change what happens when the form validates.
3. Let validate's error display do its thing. If you need an alert instead of an error label, you can change how the error displays (check the documentation).